# Set custom shortcuts in Debian

Tags: linux, debian

I use Debian and the gnome desktop environment.
You can set custom keyboard shortcuts. 
 
For example I did [crtl+alt+t] for opening a terminal.
(the command for this is called "gnome-terminal") 
And that works.

But when I try to bind the key [F11] to "python3 /somefolder/myscript.py" and I press F11 nothing happens. (when I type the command in a terminal it works but not with this keyboard shortcut)

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What does `/somefolder/myscript.py` do? Are you sure it isn't actually being executed?

Comment: @terdon It is a command line script that I wrote for myself and it should ask me for some inputs and then create a folder and some files.

Comment: Then it can't be run as a shortcut, how would it ask for input? You need to run it in a terminal.

Comment: @terdon Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script requires input, that means it needs to be run in a terminal so you can't just run it as a shortcut. However, what you could do is to use a terminal emulator that offers an option to pass it commands and run *that* with your shortcut. For example, using `gnome-terminal`, you could assign a shortcut to this command:

```
gnome-terminal -- python3 /somefolder/myscript.py
```

That will open a terminal, run your script in it allowing you to enter input, and then exit. The terminal will stay open though.

Another approach is to use a shell alias instead. Add this line to your shell's initialization file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`):

```
alias foo="python3 /somefolder/myscript.py"
```

Then open a new  terminal and you can now run `foo` which will execute your script.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `gnome-terminal -- "python3 /somefolder/myscript.py"` to execute it in terminal and see the output.